# My Code is a c# randomly generated math quiz i need to show the result of the correct and wrong answer of the user at the end

Tags: c#

I could not do it with storing the user question as a string because of the loop because I need the result at the end I'm new to programming I need help the code is mostly done it is just the result part I'm having problems with I tried with using a string and store the user question but I couldn't find out how to store random generated questions in it.

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;
    
    namespace bpg401project_homework_1
    {
        class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Random randomgen = new Random();
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                int a; TimeSpan xs = stopWatch.Elapsed; string Sa = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                    xs.Hours, xs.Minutes, xs.Seconds,
                  xs.Milliseconds / 10); ; float p;
                //asking the user for max limit of time
                Console.Write("how much time(min) : ");
                Sa = Console.ReadLine(); a = Int32.Parse(Sa);
                Thread.Sleep(a);
// start Time
                stopWatch.Start();
    
    // generating random numbers
                int num01 = randomgen.Next(10,50);
                int num02 = randomgen.Next(10,100);
                int useranswer;
                int answer;
                int numofquestions;
                int numofquestionsleft;
                int numofcorrect = 0;
                
                
    
    
                //asking the user for max limit of questions
                Console.Write("Max Question : ");
                numofquestions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                
                numofquestionsleft = numofquestions;
    
                // This is the loop that handles the actual question/answer of the quiz.
                while (numofquestionsleft > 0)
                {
    // the question 
                    Console.Write("What is " + num01 + " / " + num02 + "? ");
                    answer = num01 % num02;
                    useranswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    
                    
                    // mines the question the have been left -1
                    numofquestionsleft--;
                    num01 = randomgen.Next(10,50);
                    num02 = randomgen.Next(10,100);
                   
                }
                   // the user answer score
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + numofcorrect + " of " + numofquestions + " correct!");
    
                // Format and display the TimeSpan value  
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                      ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    
                // letting the user know how much time did they take.
                Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
// letting the user know if they made it on time
                if (xs > ts)
                {
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry time is up , try again");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" you made it on time");
    
                }
                
                Console.ReadKey();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe consider a list of strings as one possible solution.

Comment: tried it but i dont know how to store the random questions in the loop!

Comment: @MaxXx_GAMER Do you just want to count the correct/wrong answers in `numofcorrect` or do you want to show the individual user inputs for each question?

Comment: yes the individual user input plus the question and the if its correct or not example , 2 / 2 = 3 wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a QuestionAnswer class:

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
   public string Question {get;set;}
   public int Answer {get;set;}
}
```

Modify your code to declare a List of type QuestionAnswer at the start of your program:

```
        Random randomgen = new Random();
        List<QuestionAnswer> questionAnswers = new List<QuestionAnswer>();
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
```

In your while loop store the question and answer in questionAnswer type and then add to the list:

```
             // the question 
            QuestionAnswer questionAnswer = new QuestionAnswer();

            questionAnswer.Question = "What is " + num01 + " / " + num02 + "? ";
            
            Console.Write(questionAnswer.Question);

           ...
           questionAnswer.Answer= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
           //store the question / answer in list
           questionAnswers.Add(questionAnswer);
```

Comment: thanks man it worked but its not working when I want to do a list of the user answers

Comment: The list stores both the question and the corresponding answer - so what is the problem you are having ? Do you want to store either / both ? Your question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: tried doing this list                                                                                               
          List<string> answers = new List<string>();                                                                   var answer = num01 % num02;
               answers.Add(answer); // here its telling me i have invalid arguments

Comment: that's because answer is an int not a string - do answers.Add(answer.ToString());

Comment: Well, if that helped please tick this answer as useful